# Cookie velue becomes null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, iis-7

We have a situation where in, from the View we are storing a value in the Cookie using Below javascript code :

```
document.cookie = "Test = Test Velue; "
```

And trying to read it from the Controller using `Request.Cookies["Test"].Value;` we are getting the cookie to be `NULL` in production server.

Any bright ideas on why this will happen?

We have taken a look at the cookie name and they are accurate. And it also working as exacted in local.

We are using "In Proc" session state in both local and Production server.